# .NET equivalent for php's sha1(sha1("string",true))

Tags: c#, php, .net

I'm trying to find a way to get the same output as this method in php `sha1(sha1("string",true))` but in .NET.

For example if my input is '123456789', the output should be 'cc67043c7bcff5eea5566bd9b1f3c74fd9a5cf5d'

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you double-hashing it?

Comment: @CodyGray I use a db with already made rows that uses this way of encryption.